# Running a pylinter with jenkins

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to set up a jenkins job to run my `lint.py` file. The jenkins command I am running is:

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt 
 python lint.py
```

And the output I'm seeing is:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pylint in /var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): sqlalchemy in /var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas in /var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.0 in /var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Cleaning up...
+ python lint.py
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
sh: 1: pylint: not found
['lint.py']
no directory specified, defaulting to current working directory
```

at which point the job fails.

So: the package is already installed, yet it's not being found when `lint.py` is run.

When I do this manually, I can `sudo pip install pylint`, and `lint.py` will run happily, but this isn't an option for the jenkins job. Also, I belive that this should be able to work without a `sudo`, since the package *is* installed somwhere. I have tried adding `PYTHONPATH="/var/lib/jenkins/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" python lint.py` to the command, but I got the same result.

Does anyone know what I can do to enable `lint.py` to run? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try running python in verbose mode as the jenkins user (sudo -u jenkins python -v) and see where it's looking for pylint? If it's finding it, you can figure out how to manipulate your pythonpath to make this work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pylint isn't installed. What OS are you running on? If Debian or Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install pylint
```

If this doesn't work validate the the python setup you are using is the setup you expect.

```
which python
which pip
pip freeze
```

Alternatively the following plugin might work for you:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Violations

Comment: Hi @Luke, I'm confused by your answer. In the first line of the output above, the machine clearly thinks that pylint is installed somewhere. Additionally, these jobs run on multiple computers so installing it once with `sudo apt-get install` ins't going to work.

Comment: the initial pip install seems to think that it is installed. But without validating the python and pip locations, you might have more than one python installed on the machine.